# Custom combo box in android?

Tags: android, combobox, spinner

How can i create a combo box in android like the picture bellow?

I can see only spinners in android. but i want like the picture.

Any one can help me??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom button, and on click [show a popup](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/how-to-create-popups-in-android/) with a ListView within it. 
Also on click make the popup appear below the button.

Comment: hai, Andy Res,
Is it possible to make that pop up's appearance like in my picture ?
Also i want to see the selected item in my field, if i use custom button is it possible?

Comment: If you go the custom way, everything is possible. A pop up is nothing but displaying an arbitrary view, So you create the layout of popup, and then display it at a specific location, in your case, below the button.

Answer (score -1):

NewQuickAction3D is a small android library to create QuickAction dialog with Gallery3D app style.

try [this](https://github.com/chemalarrea/DemoSlidingDrawer/tree/f1d5829734721f250166fa12543d9fbe77f03ed6/lorensiuswlt-NewQuickAction3D-4273b56)

hope help you..